# factorization of a joint distribution

Tags: joint-distribution

I have a question regarding the factorization of the following joint density:

$P(Y, v, \psi , \theta)= P(Y |v, \psi)P(v, \psi|  \theta) P(\theta)$

My question is:

when I try write each of the conditional distribution as nominator over denominator for example for the first conditional distribution on the right as:

$ P(Y |v, \psi)$ = $\frac{P(Y, v, \psi)}{P(v, \psi)}$,

and then multiply each of those "numberator and denominator", the multiplication of nominator or cancellation of nominator with denominator don't equal to the term:

It is the first formula in this article here:
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pierre_Yves_Boelle/publication/8211096_A_Bayesian_MCMC_approach_to_study_transmission_of_Influenza_application_to_household_longitudinal_data/links/548f1e5c0cf214269f26366e.pdf

$P(Y, v, \psi , \theta)$

Could someone explain or shine some light?

thank you

Comment: Looks like a $\theta$ is missing in the first factor on the right hand side?

Comment: Hi, it is actually an article in here:  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pierre_Yves_Boelle/publication/8211096_A_Bayesian_MCMC_approach_to_study_transmission_of_Influenza_application_to_household_longitudinal_data/links/548f1e5c0cf214269f26366e.pdf

Comment: It is the formula 1 in the article. Probably $\theta$ is not part of the first conditional distribution on the right hand side because when you look at the first like right after formula 1 in the article, the author still didn't include the $\theta$ term in the distribution of the first conditional distribution.